# Php mysql tabs don't output

Tags: php, mysql

My question is if I insert in `mysql` the content from a `textarea` and echo it out the tabs and spaces are missing. How to solve this?

```
$data=$_POST["from_textarea"];
```

then insert to `mysql` with a query.

and using a select query get it back and echo it.

Comment: That question must be favorited! Please describe your problem better and post code if you want help.

Comment: Do you mean that web browsers collapse white space in HTML documents?

Comment: you're probably dumping into an HTML context, where tabs/extra spaces are ignored...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS on your display element:

```
.lineBreaks {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

For example in your page:

```
<div style="white-space:pre-line">
    <?php echo $mysqlData ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It doesn't add spaces and tabs.

Comment: I'm sorry mate, but you're honestly going to have to give us all more information, how are you displaying the information? What is the output using `var_dump()` or the variable holding the database information?